# How to disable the overscolling of a gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, overscroll

I have an Android application using  a GridView.
This gridview automatically overscrolls when users make a vertical scroll. I can't use `setOverScrollMode(...)` because its minimum sdk version is 2.2.(Api 8).

How can I disable the overscolling of GridView?

Answer (score 1):

can you just do as following:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
                    mListView.setOverScrollMode(ListView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

            }
```

but the drawback is that the if you add a headerview on the listview, the headerview tends to be bounce back when you fling . I was wondering how to avoid that.